# in R, check if string appears in row of dataframe (in any column)

Tags: r

```
temp = structure(list(name1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Joe", 
"Mike"), class = "factor"), name2 = c("Nick", "Matt", "Nick", 
"Matt", "Nick"), name3 = c("Matt", "Tom", "Tom", "Steve", "Tom"
)), .Names = c("name1", "name2", "name3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Hi all,

I have what feels like a simple coding question for R. See the following dataframe below, the code for which is above:

```
  name1 name2 name3
1  Mike  Nick  Matt
2   Joe  Matt   Tom
3  Mike  Nick   Tom
4   Joe  Matt Steve
5  Mike  Nick   Tom
```

I would like a simple function that returns a boolean vector indicating if a particular name appears in a row (in any column) of this dataframe. For example:

```
myfunction(Matt) 

# should return
c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE).
```

since Matt appears in the 1st, 2nd and 4th rows. Any simple help with this is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an option. Use `apply` and match (`%in%`).

```
apply(temp, 1, function(x) any(x %in% "Matt")) 
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 8):

I've come up with my own solution as well:

```
rowSums("Matt" == temp) > 0
```

seems to do the trick

Comment: That's a usually neat way to do it. I'll also suggest `Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(temp, \`==\`, "Matt"))`

Comment: `rowSums` or `Reduce` are also about 20 times faster than looping over each row in `apply`, and about 60 times faster than using `by_row` in `dplyr/purrr`

Answer (score 5):

This solution used `dplyr` and `purrr`.

```
myFunction <- function(df, name) {
  by_row(df, function(x) {name %in% x}, .collate = "cols") %>%
    pull(.out)
}
myFunction(temp, "Matt")
```

`by_row` adds the boolean as a column. `pull` returns the column as a vector.

**Update**: `by_row` function has been removed from `purrr`

Comment: Is `by_row` from purrrlyr, not dplyr or purrr?

Comment: @camille, at the time of writing the answer it was part of the `purrr`, but has since been deprecated in that library. Looks like the function is now in `purrrlyr` as you pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

There are other very consistent and more general approaches with dplyr or purrr, so you can avoid the problems that come from class coercion associated with the conversion to matrixes in `apply()`, the inefficiencies and verbose codes of for loops or other limitations that come from the `rowSums` proposal.

**with purrr’s map, reduce and stringr’s str_detect:**

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

temp%>%map(~str_detect(.x,'Matt'))%>%reduce(`|`)
```

**With dplyr, using `map%>%reduce`, `pmap%>%any`, `rowwise%>%any` or `if_any`:**

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

temp%>%mutate(has_Matt=map(., ~str_detect(.x, 'Matt'))%>%pmap_lgl(any))

#OR

temp%>%rowwise()%>%
        mutate(has_Matt=any(str_detect(c_across(everything()), "Matt")))
```

**The most concise, with dplyr::if_any:**

```
temp%>%mutate(has_Matt=if_any(everything(), ~.x=="Matt"))
```

If you want to define a new function that simplifies this operation, you can create a function with base R:

```
my_function<-function(dataframe, pattern){
        Reduce(`|`, Map(function(x) grepl('Matt', x), dataframe))
}

my_function(temp, "Matt")

[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```