# How to find if ANY column has a specific value I am looking for?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

```
   id first  middle  last       Age
    1 Carol  Jenny   Smith      15
    2 Sarah  Carol   Roberts    20
    3 Josh   David   Richardson 22
```

I am trying find a specific name in ANY of the name columns (first, middle, last). For example, if I found anyone with a name Carol (doesn't matter if it's the first/middle/last name), I want to mutate a column 'Carol' and give 1. So what I want is the following

```
   id first  middle  last       Age  Carol
    1 Carol   Jenny   Smith      15   1
    2 Sarah  Carol   Roberts    20    1
    3 Josh   David   Richardson 22    0
```

I have been trying 
ifelse(c(first, middle,last)  == "Carol"   , 1, 0 )
or "Carol" %in% first...etc
but for some reason I can only work on one column instead of multiple columns.. Could anyone help me please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in R, check if string appears in row of dataframe (in any column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827337/in-r-check-if-string-appears-in-row-of-dataframe-in-any-column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df$Carol <- as.integer(rowSums(df[2:4] == "Carol") > 0)

df
#  id first middle       last Age Carol
#1  1 Carol  Jenny      Smith  15     1
#2  2 Sarah  Carol    Roberts  20     1
#3  3  Josh  David Richardson  22     0
```

If we need it as a function

```
fun <- function(df, value) {
   as.integer(rowSums(df[2:4] == value) > 0)
}

fun(df, "Carol")
#[1] 1 1 0
fun(df, "Sarah")
#[1] 0 1 0
```

but this assumes the columns you want to search are at position `2:4`.

To give more flexibility with column position

```
fun <- function(df, cols, value) {
   as.integer(rowSums(df[cols] == value) > 0)
 }
fun(df, c("first", "last","middle"), "Carol")
#[1] 1 1 0
fun(df, c("first", "last","middle"), "Sarah")
#[1] 0 1 0
```

Comment: i see..why can't we use ifelse here though? just wondering..is it possible to use mutate?

Comment: @Molly we can but then it would not scale up. Imagine you need to this for 10-20 columns.

Comment: My solution simply uses mutate and if_else and works, but as @RonakShah pointed out it is to much work if scaled up to multiple columns.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `tidyverse` option. We first reshape the data to long format, group by `id`, and find levels of `id` that have the desired name in at least one row. Then we reshape back to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, first:last) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(Carol = as.numeric(any(value=="Carol"))) %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

> ```
>      id   Age Carol first last       middle
> 1     1    15     1 Carol Smith      Jenny 
> 2     2    20     1 Sarah Roberts    Carol 
> 3     3    22     0 Josh  Richardson David
> ```

Or, as a function:

```
find.target = function(data, target) {

  data %>% 
    gather(key, value, first:last) %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(!!target := as.numeric(any(value==target))) %>% 
    spread(key, value) %>% 
    # Move new target column to end
    select(-target, target)

}

find.target(df, "Carol")
find.target(df, "Sarah")
```

You could also do several at once. For example:

```
map(c("Sarah", "Carol", "David"), ~ find.target(df, .x)) %>% 
  reduce(left_join)
```

> ```
>      id   Age first last       middle Sarah Carol David
> 1     1    15 Carol Smith      Jenny      0     1     0
> 2     2    20 Sarah Roberts    Carol      1     1     0
> 3     3    22 Josh  Richardson David      0     0     1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
f1 <- function(data, wordToCompare, colsToCompare) {
          wordToCompare <- enquo(wordToCompare)
          data %>%
              select(colsToCompare) %>%
              mutate(!! wordToCompare :=  map(.,  ~ 
       .x == as_label(wordToCompare)) %>% 
           reduce(`|`) %>%
           as.integer)
              }
          
f1(df1, Carol, c("first", 'middle', 'last'))
# first middle       last Carol
#1 Carol  Jenny      Smith     1
#2 Sarah  Carol    Roberts     1
#3  Josh  David Richardson     0

f1(df1, Sarah, c("first", 'middle', 'last'))
#   first middle       last Sarah
#1 Carol  Jenny      Smith     0
#2 Sarah  Carol    Roberts     1
#3  Josh  David Richardson     0
```

---

Or this can also be done with `pmap`

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(Carol = pmap_int(.[c('first', 'middle', 'last')],
          ~ +('Carol' %in% c(...))))
#   id first middle       last Age Carol
#1  1 Carol  Jenny      Smith  15     1
#2  2 Sarah  Carol    Roberts  20     1
#3  3  Josh  David Richardson  22     0
```

which can be wrapped into a function

```
f2 <- function(data, wordToCompare, colsToCompare) {
      wordToCompare <- enquo(wordToCompare)
      data %>%
           mutate(!! wordToCompare := pmap_int(.[colsToCompare],
          ~ +(as_label(wordToCompare) %in% c(...))))
  } 

f2(df1, Carol, c("first", 'middle', 'last'))
#  id first middle       last Age Carol
#1  1 Carol  Jenny      Smith  15     1
#2  2 Sarah  Carol    Roberts  20     1
#3  3  Josh  David Richardson  22     0
```

NOTE: Both the tidyverse methods doesn't require any reshaping

---

With `base R`, we can loop through the 'first', 'middle', 'last' column and use `==` for comparison to get a `list` of logical `vector`s, which we `Reduce` to a single logical `vector` with `|` and coerce it to binary with `+`

```
df1$Carol <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1[2:4], `==`, 'Carol')))
df1
#  id first middle       last Age Carol
#1  1 Carol  Jenny      Smith  15     1
#2  2 Sarah  Carol    Roberts  20     1 
#3  3  Josh  David Richardson  22     0
```

---

NOTE: There are dupes for this post.  For e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45827337/in-r-check-if-string-appears-in-row-of-dataframe-in-any-column)

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, first = c("Carol", "Sarah", "Josh"), 
middle = c("Jenny", "Carol", "David"), last = c("Smith", 
"Roberts", "Richardson"), Age = c(15L, 20L, 22L)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `apply` family

```
df$Carol = lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) any(df[x,]=="Carol))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `mutate` and `if_else()` as you suggested:

```
library(tidyverse)

data = read_table("   id first  middle  last       Age
    1 Carol  Jenny   Smith      15
    2 Sarah  Carol   Roberts    20
    3 Josh   David   Richardson 22")
data %>%
  mutate(carol = if_else(first == "Carol" | middle == "Carol" | last == "Carol",
                         "yes",
                         "no"))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
     id first middle last         Age carol
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>
1     1 Carol Jenny  Smith         15 yes  
2     2 Sarah Carol  Roberts       20 yes  
3     3 Josh  David  Richardson    22 no
```